# CSV file not loading correctly in Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv

I've seen a couple of similar questions but have not had one that answers my issue.

I have an export to CSV button which exports results from my database to CSV.

I don't want to save the file, but I just want to use headers to export the *echo* content to a file which should then be opened in Excel (or similar product).

All works fine but Excel does not appear to separate the values, but rather shows all rows in 1 row with the commas intact. I found a solution elsewhere where I should add "sep=,\r\n" to the first line to tell Excel to use commas as the delimiter, which then makes it work great; but, in other products it now shows the sep=, on the first line and continues with the remaining of the output.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-control: private");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv");
 echo "sep=,\r\n"; // This makes it work in excel but fails in other products such as openoffice
 echo "this,is,just,a,test\r\n";
 exit;
```

Comment: The character separator that you need for MS Excel is locale-specific.... use `;` for locales that use a `,` as a thousands separator; or `,` for other locales. Alteratively, create an Excel BIFF or OfficeOpenXML file, and this problem simply doesn't arise

Comment: I'm not sure about Excel, but OpenOffice makes me choose which delimiters I want to use for a table when I open it. You might want to use the default delimiter for Excel if you want best compatibility for both - that is - without having a selection for the user before they download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark Baker suggested, as the dilimeter is set by locale settings, I changed it to ; and it worked like a charm :) Thank you!