# CSV file in Excel is not rendering correctly

Tags: excel, csv

This is the content of the excel file:

```
"Windows Excel","AndroMoney","20140227"
"Id","Valuta","Importo","Categoria","Sottocategoria","Data","Spese(Trasferimento Out)","Entrate(Trasferimento In)","Note","Periodicita'","Progetto","Pagatore/Beneficiario","uid"
"19","EUR","-1079.63","SYSTEM","INIT_AMOUNT","10100101","","Bank","","","","","116EUR-1079.63_26_102"
"20","EUR","-2662.9","SYSTEM","INIT_AMOUNT","10100101","","Credit Card","","","","","117EUR-2662.9_26_102"
"960","EUR","0","SYSTEM","INIT_AMOUNT","10100101","","Bank austria","","","","","265C6BD548CE41FEA0250BF4E19C392F"
"1","EUR","8","Food","Breakfast","20130326","Cash","","","","","","1EUR8_1_1"
```

And here is how Excel shows its content:

[image]

In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123423/csv-file-not-loading-correctly-in-excel#comment24777790_17123423) they say it's due to the usage of the **,** instead of **;**

Is it possible to solve the problem without changing Operating System settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a trick.

Change the extencion from CSV to TXT, the open the file with excel, define **,** as the delimitator character

Answer (score 2):

You can select column `A` and go to Data - Text to Columns. Then use delimited and define `,` as the delimiter. This will delimit the data and show it correctly.

If you're asking how to make it delimit based on the comma when you open it, I didn't read the question that way. But instead of double-clicking the file to open, go to the Data tab and Get External Data from it, defining the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010 and newer csv files are read correctly. In older versions you need to specify a separator during import in text import wizard.

Comment: mmm.. But the software I'm using is Excel 2010.. and seem not to work