# PHP exports results from my database to CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have a problem to export data to cvs file
my problem is same of this
[CSV file in Excel is not rendering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073756/csv-file-in-excel-is-not-rendering-correctly?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I have used the proposed solutions but the problem persists
I tested it on excel 2013 and excel 2007
I want the file to be automatically opened by excel

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=cars.csv');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    $csvoutput = fopen('php://output', 'w');
   //$str="sep=,";
   //fputcsv($csvoutput,$str );
   //echo "sep=,\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution does not work because it have empty rows in the php script.
Therefore it is necessary to remove all the spaces so that the line

```
echo "sep =, \ r \ n";
```

is the first.